# Laravel, action triggers. How to structure?

Tags: php, laravel, triggers

I haven't seen anyone doing this, so i'm bit confused if it can be good approach.

Some small system with login. And i have simple group management withing that system. I want to be able to easily set and execute some triggers depending of action and on group in which user belongs.

First idea that came to my mind is to have in groups table 4 fields for triggers, named like this:

- add_triggers (when user is added to trigger this)
- delete_triggers (when user is removed from a group)
- login_triggers (when user logs in to be triggered)
- logout_triggers (when user logout to be triggered)

Now i'm wondering how to relate that to an actual trigger code?

Should i have separated class triggers that should receive just "names" of triggers and in that class to hold all possible trigger's code? So that i'm able to execute that in some kind of a loop?

Does anyone have any other idea how to organize that?

p.s. those groups are quite an important part of a system. Most of the things should be based on them. They even has extending tables for complex type of groups.

thnx

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is [Laravel Events](http://laravel.com/docs/events).

I would definetly recommend making a class that the event calls rather than writing procedural style code.

`Event::listen('auth.login', 'LoginHandler@onLogin');`

Comment: I have many groups, i have many different events, for example:
add user in a active directory, create online account in office 365, add user in printing system, add user to be able to connect to wireless, send sms when certain user logs in, set some notification for users in certain group when they login.. etc...
would that be possible to do it with events?